# Ksoap2 Error reading XMLStreamReader on android

Tags: java, android, soap, android-ksoap2, ksoap

I'm trying to make a soap request via ksoap2 on android and I'm getting a soapfault that says "Error reading XMLStreamReader."  I'm not sure what's causing this and I'll give out as much information as I can about what we're using but some of the stuff is confidential.  In any event, we just really want to get this thing live.  Any suggestions would be great.  The error is thrown on (SoapObject)env.getResponse();

```
try
                            {
                                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                                SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                                SoapObject internalObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "groupId");
                                PropertyInfo props = new PropertyInfo();
                                props.setName("groupId");
                                props.setValue("omitted");
                                props.setType(String.class);
                                internalObject.addAttribute("groupId", "omitted");
                                internalObject.addProperty(props);
                                request.addSoapObject(internalObject);

                                internalObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"password");
                                props = new PropertyInfo();
                                props.setName("password");
                                props.setValue("omitted");
                                props.setType(String.class);
                                internalObject.addAttribute("password", "omitted");
                                internalObject.addProperty(props);
                                request.addSoapObject(internalObject);

                                internalObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"userId");
                                props = new PropertyInfo();
                                props.setName("userId");
                                props.setValue("omitted");
                                props.setType(String.class);
                                internalObject.addAttribute("userId", "omitted");
                                internalObject.addProperty(props);
                                request.addSoapObject(internalObject);

                                internalObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"xml");
                                String xmlFile = InspectDataDriver.buildXml();
                                props = new PropertyInfo();
                                props.setName("xml");
                                props.setValue("<! [CDATA [" + omitted.buildXml() + "]]");
                                props.setType(String.class);
                                internalObject.addAttribute("xml", "<! [CDATA [" + xmlFile + "]]" );
                                internalObject.addProperty(props);
                                request.addSoapObject(internalObject);

                                internalObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"agentId");
                                props = new PropertyInfo();
                                props.setName("agentId");
                                props.setValue("omitted");
                                props.setType(String.class);
                                internalObject.addAttribute("agentId", "omitted" );
                                internalObject.addProperty(props);
                                request.addSoapObject(internalObject);

                                internalObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"agentGroupId");
                                props = new PropertyInfo();
                                props.setName("agentGroupId");
                                props.setValue("omitted");
                                props.setType(String.class);
                                internalObject.addAttribute("agentGroupId", "omitted" );
                                internalObject.addProperty(props);
                                request.addSoapObject(internalObject);

                                internalObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"reportFormat");
                                props = new PropertyInfo();
                                props.setName("reportFormat");
                                props.setValue("XML");
                                props.setType(String.class);
                                internalObject.addAttribute("reportFormat", "XML" );
                                internalObject.addProperty(props);
                                request.addSoapObject(internalObject);

                                internalObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"reportFormat");
                                props = new PropertyInfo();
                                props.setName("detailedReport");
                                props.setValue("NO");
                                props.setType(String.class);
                                internalObject.addAttribute("detailedReport", "NO");
                                internalObject.addProperty(props);
                                request.addSoapObject(internalObject);

                                internalObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"valuationId");
                                props = new PropertyInfo();
                                props.setName("valuationId");
                                props.setValue("999999");
                                props.setType(String.class);
                                internalObject.addAttribute("valuationId", "999999");
                                internalObject.addProperty(props);
                                request.addSoapObject(internalObject);

                                internalObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"version");
                                props = new PropertyInfo();
                                props.setName("version");
                                props.setValue("1");
                                props.setType(String.class);
                                internalObject.addAttribute("version", "1");
                                internalObject.addProperty(props);
                                request.addSoapObject(internalObject);

                                env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                                env.dotNet = false;
                                env.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;


                                HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                                ht.debug = true;

                                ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, env);

                                final SoapObject response = (SoapObject)env.getResponse();
                                final String str = ht.responseDump;
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                                {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        AlertDialog.Builder mBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(ItemListActivity.this);
                                        mBuild.setMessage(str);
                                        AlertDialog mDialog = mBuild.create();
                                        mDialog.show();                                         
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `env.getResponse();` is returning something valid before trying to cast it?

Comment: before the cast env's bodyIn says "SoapFault" cause=SoapFault faultcode=soap.client faultstring="Error reading XMLStreamReader"

Comment: Solved the problem by not using ksoap2 and instead built a request on my own and sent it through a DefaultHttpClient with the request as a HttpEntity.